# My apps are enlarged on Ubuntu, how to change overall settings for it?

Tags: unity, launcher, display-resolution, cinnamon, resize

I'm using 1980x1080 monitors. Chrome, IntelliJ and Terminals are kind of enlarged. Their texts are kind of huge. Apparently it has something to do with Unity Environment. I've tried Cinnamon environment on the same Ubuntu Linux, and the sizes are perfectly fine over there. Is there a way to tweak overall enlarged apps?

I'm using GTX 750 with proprietary driver.

Comment: What version of  ubuntu are you using ?

Comment: Using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: In Settings > Screens you can 1. check whether the correct resolution is being used and adjust accordingly and 2. scale fonts and bars.